# RouteComponentProps location state property does not exists on type {}

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

We start getting this kind of errors. Before the code was getting copiled as usual and we dont have any error on the compilation process.
But now some guys that installed the react application from scratch start getting this error only when we route to a new page and try to ready properties form the location state.

[Ts Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaqbk.png)

This is what we are doing for read the state that was working before:

```
    interface IPageProps extends RouteComponentProps {...}
interface IState  {
  from: string;
  to: string;
}
    class Page extends Component<IPageProps, IState> {
    constructor(props: IPageProps) {
    super(props);
    const {
      location: { state: routeState },
      history,
    } = props;
    this.state = {
      from: routeState && routeState.from ? routeState.from : '',
      to: routeState && routeState.to ? routeState.to : ''
    };
  }
  }
```

So the errors are in routeState.from and routeState.to

The versions of the react-routes:

```
  "@types/react-router": "^5.1.1",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.5",
      "react-router": {
          "version": "5.1.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-router/-/react-router-5.1.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-yjEuMFy1ONK246B+rsa0cUam5OeAQ8pyclRDgpxuSCrAlJ1qN9uZ5IgyKC7gQg0w8OM50NXHEegPh/ks9YuR2A==",
          "requires": {
            "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
            "history": "^4.9.0",
            "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.1.0",
            "loose-envify": "^1.3.1",
            "mini-create-react-context": "^0.3.0",
            "path-to-regexp": "^1.7.0",
            "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
            "react-is": "^16.6.0",
            "tiny-invariant": "^1.0.2",
            "tiny-warning": "^1.0.0"
          }
        },
"react-router-dom": {
  "version": "5.1.2",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-router-dom/-/react-router-dom-5.1.2.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-7BPHAaIwWpZS074UKaw1FjVdZBSVWEk8IuDXdB+OkLb8vd/WRQIpA4ag9WQk61aEfQs47wHyjWUoUGGZxpQXew==",
  "requires": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "loose-envify": "^1.3.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react-router": "5.1.2",
    "tiny-invariant": "^1.0.2",
    "tiny-warning": "^1.0.0"
  }
},
```

Does any one have the same issue? How did you solve it?

The concern is that this was not happening before and start to happen now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this caused by https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/41674 ?

Answer (score 0):

In your declaration:

```
interface IPageProps extends RouteComponentProps {...}
```

Are you putting location in that? It appears that you are not getting location and/or location.state from anywhere which is why that error is occuring: if you look at [this link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/location.md) it might help you a little bit with react-router.

Comment: That Interface extend RouteComponentProps that already have a definition for location.state correct?